Можно ли в регулярном выражении использовать переменные?
Например есть текст:
text1,text2
text3,text3
text4,text5

Мне нужно найти в нем только строку "text3,text3", т.е. там где text3 = text3
Я где-то читал что можно использовать переменные $1,$2..., но не знаю как их применять.
Пробовал, например так:
(\w+),$1
Но не работает. Возможно ли одним ругулярным выражением осуществить такой поиск?

внезапно, регулярные выражения бывают с весьма разным синтаксисом и весьма разных реализаций. так что уточните, прямо в тексте вопроса (и метках), про какую именно реализацию движка регулярных выражений вы спрашиваете.

PCRE использую.


Мне нужно найти в нем только строку "text3,text3", т.е. там где text3 = text3 Я где-то читал что можно использовать переменные $1,$2..., но не знаю как их применять.

Это не переменные... Это ссылка на номер запомненной в скобках подстроки.


const t = `text1,text2
text3,text3
text4,text5`
const r = /([^,]+),\1/
console.log(t.match(r)[0])



